# SQL Increase value in column by percentage and out from criteria in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

So I've got two tables where i wanna use both tables.

The first.

**Factory** (`fid`, `fname`, `address`)

and

**Worker** (`wid`, `wname`, `fid`, `salary`)

I wanna increase the salary of workers who are working on a factory with more than 100 workers by 10%.

How is this done?

Is it the `fid` of the factory that needs to be searched if it has over 100 id's or?

Comment: Do you need actually to do `UPDATE` or just output new salaries with `SELECT`?

Comment: I need to both update the database and output it. Is it possible in one query?

Comment: What is your RDBMS (`SQL Server`, `Oracle`, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in one query in [`PostgeSQL`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) by using `UPDATE ... RETURNING *`

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by and having clause to get the fid which have more than 100 employees as follows.

```
select fid from Worker  group by fid  having count(wid) > 100
```

In case you want to increase the salary by 10% then use fid fetched in first query and update

```
update Worker set salary = salary * 1.1 where fid IN (select fid from Worker  group by fid  having count(wid) > 100)

10% of salary = 1.1 * salary
```

Comment: Check your `GROUP BY`. Aldo can you streamline your 10% increase arithmetic?

Comment: @PM Thanks. It was typo mistake. I changed the column name to correct value in GROUP BY Clause. Hope it work now

Comment: `SET salary = 1.1 * salary`